# create forum with xmpp pubsub

Tags: javascript, xmpp, publish-subscribe, openfire, ejabberd

i just wanted to know if I want a collection node act as topic and this collection node has leaf nodes for different questions wouldn't it be highly inefficient to have a dedicated leaf nodes for each question (collection node-leaf1, leaf2, ..., leafN)? This will end up with thousands of different leaf nodes in the database for different questions and not just items (for questions and answers) in one leaf node per topic (collection node)... (collection node-leaf node (where Q&A with big chunk of logic assigning answers to questions))

Or are collection and leaf nodes just made for such cases (a lot of leafs for each question)?

Edit1: Shouldn't I use XMPP for that purpose?